# Swift:SQLite error with "default label can only appear inside a switch statement"

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, swift2

I am really unfamiliar with the SQLite even any database

I'm learning how to use it

But there are some error appear

like this photo

[image: http://imgur.com/a/3Z5Tn]

Have any idea?

Above is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var db :sqliteConnect?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // 資料庫檔案的路徑
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(
        for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let sqlitePath = urls[urls.count-1].absoluteString + "sqlite3.db"

        // 印出儲存檔案的位置
        print(sqlitePath)

        // SQLite 資料庫
        db = SQLiteConnect(path: sqlitePath)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have tagged the question with [swift2.3], but your code looks like Swift 3. Please clarify which version you plan to use.

Comment: Looks like you're using Swift 3 (Xcode 8) in Xcode 7 (which accepts Swift 2.x only) - it can't work.